# ORA-00936: missing expression with Python and Oracle on insert

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have spent many days trying to figure out the ORA-00936: missing expression error when using the executemany().  If I insert one row at a time, the insert works.
I have searched, read, and tried suggestions found on the internet but none of them seem to work.
I need help.
here is the table description:

```
ColumnName,ColID,PK,IndexPos,Null,DataType,Default,DefaultOnNull,Histogram,NumDistinct,NumNulls,Density,EncryptionAlg,Salt,Trigger,Virtual
YEARMONTH,1,1,1,N,DATE,,False,None,1997,0,0.0005,,,,False
PHASE,4,,,Y,VARCHAR2 (7 Char),,False,Frequency,5,0,0.00013,,,,False
INDEXVALUE,3,,,Y,NUMBER (3,2),,False,None,728,0,0.00137,,,,False
CLIMATEINDEX,2,2,2,N,VARCHAR2 (4 Char),,False,Frequency,3,0,0.00013,,,,False
```

The data is read from a csv file with python's csv reader and put into a list.
Here is the data:

```
file_data = [['1854-01-01', 'PDO', '0.11', 'POS'], ['1854-02-01', 'PDO', '-0.24', 'NEG'], ['1854-03-01', 'PDO', '-0.4', 'NEG'], ['1854-04-01', 'PDO', '-0.44', 'NEG'], ['2020-04-01', 'ONI', '0.28', 'NEUTRAL'], ['2020-04-01', 'PDO', '-1.33', 'NEG'], ['2020-05-01', 'PDO', '-0.7', 'NEG']]
```

This is the insert sql:

```
in_query = ('insert into myschema.monthly_climate_index(YEARMONTH, CLIMATEINDEX, INDEXVALUE, PHASE) values (DATE :YEARMONTH, :CLIMATEINDEX, :INDEXVALUE, :PHASE)')
```

This is the execute many command:

```
cursor.executemany(in_query, file_data)
```

The result is:  ORA-00936: missing expression
THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
insert into myschema.monthly_climate_index
  (YEARMONTH, CLIMATEINDEX, INDEXVALUE, PHASE) values 
  (DATE :YEARMONTH, :CLIMATEINDEX, :INDEXVALUE, :PHASE)
   ---------------
   ^^^ this
```

I don't think that you can use date that way; `date` keyword looks as if you wanted to insert a date literal, e.g. `date '2020-06-18'`. If that's so, *everything* should be part of the `:YEARMONTH`.

Comment: You are right, Thanks!  I couldn't use 'DATE' in that manner.  I tried this, TO_DATE(:YEARMONTH,'yyyy-mm-dd') and it worked..

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Update your SQL to this:

```
in_query = """ insert into myschema.monthly_climate_index(YEARMONTH, CLIMATEINDEX, INDEXVALUE, PHASE) values (:1, :2, :3, :4) """
```

And if that still doesn't work, try changing your list to an array of tuples like this

```
[('1854-01-01', 'PDO', '0.11', 'POS')]
```

Also, Oracle dates are tricky to work with. So, if date compatibility is the problem, try changing your date string literals to something like this:

```
'01-JAN-1854'
```

instead of

```
'1854-01-01'
```